# Injecting App as a parameter vs Import App from server.js in loopBack framework

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback3 and I'm thinking about optimising the codebase now, what is the point of injecting the application object as a parameter to **getUser** method from **afterRemote** hook https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Remote-hooks.html, if I can access loopback instance by requiring it directly inside **userService.ts.**

I feel that I'm missing something important here, I tried to summarise below

A. For me importing is better since I will have less code and, there
   will be no need to inject the app each time.

B. Injected and Imported
   objects are equal, _.isEqual(app, App)

C. I've checked the
   performance with process.hrtime() and got same results.

**app/models/activity.ts**

```
import {UserService} from 'app/service/userService';
import {Attach} from 'app/models/remote/activityRemote';

export = function (Activity) {

  Activity.afterRemote('find', function (ctx, result, next) {
    UserService.getUser(Activity.app, Activity.username)
      .then(() => next())
      .catch(next);
  });


  /**
   * attach remote
   */
  Attach(Activity);
};
```

**userService.ts**

```
import {Server} from 'app/server/interface/server';
import * as App from 'app/server/server';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

/**
 * @class UserService
 */
export class UserService {

  /**
   * get user's public profile
   * @param {Server} app loopback app
   * @param {string} username
   * @returns {Promise<User>}
   */
  public static getUser(app: Server, username: string): Promise<User> {

    return App.models.user.findOne(filter) // Equal and 
    return app.models.user.findOne(filter) // does the same
      .then((user: User) => {
        if (!user) {
          return Promise.reject(ServerError.get('User not found', 404));
        }

        return Promise.resolve(user);
      });
  }
}
```

**server.ts**

```
import {Server} from 'app/server/interface/server';
import * as loopback from 'loopback';
import * as boot from 'loopback-boot';

let App: Server = loopback();

module.exports = App;
export = App;

App.start = () => {
  return App.listen(() => {
    const baseUrl = App.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    App.emit('started');

    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);

    if (App.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      console.log(
        'Browse your REST API at %s%s',
        baseUrl,
        App.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath
      );
    }
  });
};


boot(App, __dirname, (err: Error) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  if (require.main === module) {
    App.start();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have multiple loopback applications in the same process going around, then you have no reason to pass the application as a parameter. Just `import` the app as it's more readable and cleaner.

Also you don't need to use `Promise.resolve` when you already have a promise:

```
return app.models.user.findOne(filter) // does the same
  .then((user: User) => {
    if (!user) {
      throw ServerError.get('User not found', 404);
    }

    return user;
  });
```

This will have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) 
It's not clear what is "multiple loopback applications" could you give me an example of such case, please?

Comment: Basically if you call `loopback()` multiple times for any reason. In testing you might do that(here's an [example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/v3.11.1/test/app.test.js#L24)). If that happens, you probably wouldn't just be able to import the main file and get the loopback application easily, you'd have to pass it around.

Comment: Looks like its returning the same instance both for "this.app", "import * as loopback from 'loopback'" and for https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/v3.11.1/test/app.test.js#L24.
Since Module._load is caching required modules.

source: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/

Comment: Yes, unless you clean your modules cache, each module is only run once and it's exports are cached. So in your case, you always get the same app.